# Jquery mobile transitions

Tags: jquery-mobile, transition

first time using jquery mobile version.

why does this not work?

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-transition="Fade">
```

I want to onClick have the content fading in, but it does not happen, it just appears roughly and no smooth at all.

Thanks

Pluda

Comment: Do you use Firefox? Transitions don't work for me in Firefox- but they work in webkit browsers. (chrome, safari,...)

Answer (score 2):

Transitions are made with new advanced features, not with javascript.
Implementing them with javascrtipt would be heavy and cumbersome. That's why they don't work in <del>most</del> **old** browsers <del>yet</del>. (AFAIK most browsers support them in new releases)

Answer (score 1):

Also, the transition name should be lower case:

data-transition="fade"